# Comecei a estudar Java Script, e estou tendo um problema com o meu código ( de um exercício). E não faço idéia de como resolver o problema

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function val(x, y, z) {
    if (x !== undefined && y === undefined && z === undefined) {
        return x;
    } else if(x !== undefined && y !== undefined) {
        return x + y;
    } else if(x === undefined && y === undefined && z === undefined) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return (x + y) / z;  // aqui ele não retorna o valor certo
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre porque seu código está entrando na seguinte condição:

```
else if(x !== undefined && y !== undefined)
```

Isso porque as duas verificações do `if` são satisfeitas para que ela seja executada, para resolver este incidente você pode incluir uma terceira verificação neste `if`, semelhante a realizada nas condições anteriores, onde é verificado se o terceiro valor (neste caso `z`) é igual a `undefined`

```
else if(x !== undefined && y !== undefined && z === undefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

Não respondendo seu problema diretamente...

Você está sem saber pra onde ir porque não consegue isolar em qual parte do seu código fica o problema.

Primeiro: Eu recomendo fortemente você estudar como usar um debugger (depurador). Esta ferramenta te ajudará a isolar os problemas do seu código. Darei aqui uma visão mais generalizada, daqui você pode pesquisar mais especificamente:

- se seu código estiver rodando no servidor (node.js), verifique como configurar o seu editor de texto (provavelmente VS Code) pra executar esse código em modo depurador;
- se você estiver rodando o código em um navegador (em uma página HTML), pesquise como usar o debugger das Ferramentas de Desenvolvedor (F12).

Continuando:

Sabendo usar um depurador, você pode avançar a execução de seu código linha a linha, verificando o valor de todas as variáveis, e então **isolar** uma linha que não esteja dando o resultado que você esperava.

Por exemplo, imagina que você esteva esperado que o cursor entrasse dentro de um IF `else if(x !== undefined && y !== undefined)`, mas não entrou. Você está agora mais perto da fonte do problema. Você pode copiar a condição dentro do IF e colar no console pra confirmar, e fazer testes mais detalhados.

E principalmente, tendo isolado melhor a fonte do problema, você pode se direcionar melhor por soluções na internet, até suas perguntas no stack overflow serão agora bem melhor detalhadas e atendidas.